# Replace TubeBufferGeometry's contents with new TubeBufferGeometry in place, without allocation

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a mesh whose geometry is a `TubeBufferGeometry`. Each frame of an animation cycle, the path of the `TubeBufferGeometry` will change (the path will be determined by values supplied at runtime), so I want to update the geometry every frame with a new `TubeBufferGeometry`. Of course, I can update the mesh's geometry like so:

```
mesh.geometry.dispose()
mesh.geometry = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry(newPath, params)
```

But this is wasteful as it requires allocating a whole new `BufferGeometry` each frame. Ideally, I could simply give the `TubeBufferGeometry` constructor an existing geometry to overwrite, and instead of allocating a whole new geometry it would write its contents to that geometry's buffers. Something like this:

```
THREE.TubeBufferGeometry.overwrite(mesh.geometry, newPath, params)
```

(Because they'd use the same `params`, the old geometry's buffers would be sufficiently large to store the new geometry.)

Is something like this possible? Having `TubeBufferGeometry` compute the vertex positions for me is much more convenient than computing them by hand, but I just need a way for it to compute them in an existing buffer instead of allocating a new one each frame.

Answer (score 1):

The geometry generators of `three.js` are intended for a one time creation of geometries. They are not intended to use them per frame in order to animate the structure of a mesh.

This approach is in general wasteful even without allocating new buffers. You should consider to author the animation as a morph target animation in Blender.

Comment: How is this approach wasteful if I only know the new paths at runtime?

Comment: The problem is that any kind of vertex modification per frame on the CPU should be avoided. This should be done on the GPU in the vertex shader (like morph target animation). I don't know if morph targets are flexible enough for your use case but you can modify [morph target influence](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/Mesh.morphTargetInfluences) values per frame on the CPU. The actual vertex displacement is still done on the GPU.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Unfortunately I don't think I'll be able to use morph targets because the potential paths specified at runtime are just too numerous to list ahead of time